# How do I store Tomcat logs into MongoDB using Fluentd?

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, logging, fluentd

I am trying to store logs of an application from NetBeans which is using Apache Tomcat into MongoDB using Fluentd, but I couldn't store logs into MongoDB effectively.